# Выдает ошибку неопределенная переменная...что делать?

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

Есть модель Property.php:

```
class Property extends Model {    
    protected $fillable = ['imagePath', 'title'];  
}
```

Создал 2 контроллера:

```
class PropertyController extends Controller
{
public  function getIndex() {
    $properties = Property::all();
    return view('sh.index', ['properties' => $properties]);
}    }

class SearchController extends Controller
{
public function getSearch() {
    $properties = Property::all();
    return view('sh.search', ['properties' => $properties]);
}   }
```

файл routes:

```
Route::get('/', [
'uses' => 'PropertyController@getIndex',
'as'  => 'property.index'
]);
Route::get('/search', [
'uses' => 'SearchController@getSearch',
'as' => 'sh.search'
]);
```

Создал две одинаковых вьюхи search.blade.php и index.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
@foreach($properties->chunk(4) as $propertyChunk)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($propertyChunk as $property)
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">                   
               <img src="{{ $property->imagePath }}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">    
               <h3>{{ $property->title }}</h3>                    
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
@endsection
```

Вьюха index.blade.php отрабатывает нормально, search.blade.php выдает такую ошибку:

```
Undefined variable: products (View: /var/www/projects/auth.laravel.com/resources/views/sh/search.blade.php)
```

Почему он не может определить переменную?

П.С.: страница search.blade.php рабочая

layouts/master.blade.php:

```
<body>
  @include('part.header')
  <div class="container content-body">
    @yield('content')
  </div>
  @include('part.footer')
</body>
```

Comment: Проверяйте `layouts.master` на наличие `$products` и правильную передачу этой переменной

Comment: добавил layouts.master...там никакой переменной $products и в помине нет!!!

Comment: Шаблон просто без @extends('layouts.master')отрабатывает?

Comment: не отрабатывает...ту же ошибку выдает....

Comment: Ну так ищите, где у вас есть `$products` и почему он не определен.

Comment: ОООО!!!!!ТОЧНО!!!!!а то я сам НЕ догадался...думаю....дай-ка я выложу на Stack Overflow, чтоб мне перевели в google-переводчике ошибку, да? за ответ +100 мог бы дать,жаль,что нельзя так ставить...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В роутах НЕ срабатывал адресс после "/".Оказалось, дело было в настройках апача! Нужно включить rewrite через консоль:

```
apache2ctl -M | grep -i rew
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```